Handling valid missing data in prediction model features
I'm developing an elastic net model using caret, with k-nearest neighbours to handle missing data in the features.
Some features are conditional on others such that a missing value is valid e.g., numeric items about pregnancy and menarche are NA for all male participants. How should I handle these?
I considered:

setting all males' values to the mean/median of the females'
responses so that there is no variation within the males; none are
present at potentially risky tails of the distribution
setting all males to another value, however, this would still have meaning for a
numeric value e.g., age of menarche at 0 would appear as extremely
early
run the model in males and females without this variable and then develop a model
in females only with this variable

